# Not receiving push messages with cellular data off, but wifi on

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications

I'm seeing strange behavior with APN: iphone4 (ios6): wifi ON, cellular data switched OFF: no push messages are received. As soon as I switch on cellular data, push messages are received again. (I use this setting because I have a tight restriction on the amount of mobile data, and want to force my iphone to use wifi only.)

I also have a wifi-only iPad, which receives push notifications as expected.

Anyone who can verify this with their setup?

Comment: it's not because of the "do not disturb" functionnality ?

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me too. iOS6 on an iPhone 4.